# Best selector for obtaining text using Cypress

Tags: jquery, cypress, selector

I'm learning best practice for Cypress selector strategies. Given that I want to get the release number from the Cypress Releases page, with the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="main-content-article-wrapper">
  <article class="main-content-article hide-scroll">
    <h1 class="main-content-title">Changelog</h1>
    <div class="nuxt-content">
      <h2 id="9-5-4">
        <a href="#9-5-4" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"><span class="icon icon-link">
             </span>
          </a>9.5.4
      </h2>
```

...what would be the optimal, future proofed selector to use to get the `9.5.4` version number text from frome the `<h2>`?

My thinking is that the `Changelog` text for the `<h1>` is unlikely to change, but the `<h2>` that contains the text is not a child nor a sibling.

So something like this?

```
cy.get("div.nuxt-content")
  .first("h2").then((txt=>{
   const versionTxt = txt.find("a").text()
   expect(versionTxt).to.equal('9.5.4')
```

However, this fails to find the targeted text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test fails because the text `'9.5.4'` is outside the `</a>` closing tag and `.text()` only gives you innerText.

Based on the HTML,

```js
cy.get("div.nuxt-content")
  .first("h2").then((txt=>{
   const versionTxt = txt.text()
   expect(versionTxt).to.equal('9.5.4')
```

or

```js
cy.get('h2[id="9-5-4"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', '9.5.4')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `include.text` to check the version number.

```js
cy.get('h2#9-5-4').should('include.text', '9.5.4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, [using `cy.contains`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Syntax) could be a viable option. It wouldn't use selectors, but may be a better solution in some cases (such as overly complex HTML that only has one element with a specific text).

```js
// Just getting the element
cy.contains('9.5.4');
// Validating element exists -- implied by above, but explicit below
cy.contains('9.5.4').should('exist');
```

Comment: I'd say using `contains` with regex would be better than using text since the release version will. be changing.

Comment: From the question, it sounded like OP only ever wants 9.5.4 -> `the optimal, future proofed selector to use to get the 9.5.4 version number text`

Comment: Ah, I must have misinterpret that.

Comment: No worries! You're definitely right if OP wants say the newest version number.